# Replace only specific group in file form preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have txt file with content:

```
fggfhfghfghf

$config['website'] = 'Olpa';


asdasdasdasdasdas
```

And PHP script for replacing by preg_replace in file:

```
write_file('tekst.txt', preg_replace('/\$config\[\'website\'] = \'(.*)\';/', 'aaaaaa', file_get_contents('tekst.txt')));
```

But it doesn't work exactly what I want it to work.

Because this script replace whole match, and after change it looks like this:

```
fggfhfghfghf

aaaaaa


asdasdasdasdasdas
```

And that's bad.

All I want is to not change whole match `$config['website'] = 'Olpa';` But to just change this `Olpa`

[image]

As you can see it belongs not to Group 2. of match information.

And all I want is to just change this Group 2. one specific thing.

to finally after script it will look like:

```
fggfhfghfghf

$config['website'] = 'aaaaaa';


asdasdasdasdasdas
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change your `preg_replace` to

```
preg_replace('/(\$config\[\'website\'] = \').*?(\';)/', '$1aaaaaa$2', file_get_contents('tekst.txt'))
```

It means, capture what you need to keep (and then use backreferences to restore the text) and just match what you need to replace.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/igzaTL/2).

**Pattern details**:

- `(\$config\[\'website\'] = \')` - Group 1 capturing a literal  `$config['website'] = '` substring (later referenced to with `$1`)
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\';)` - Group 2: a `'` followed with `;` (later referenced to with `$2`)

In case your `aaa` actually starts with a digit, you would need a `${1}`  backreference.

Answer (score 2):

I have a better, faster, leaner solution for you.  No capture groups are required, it only requires careful attention to escaping the single quotes:

Pattern: `\$config\['website'] = '\K[^']+`

`\K` means "start the fullstring match here", this combined with the negated character class (`[^']+`) affords the omission of capture groups.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UeHmCi/1) (just 25 steps)

PHP Implementation:

```
$txt='fggfhfghfghf

$config[\'website\'] = \'Olpa\';


asdasdasdasdasdas';
print_r(preg_replace('/\$config\[\'website\'\] = \'\K[^\']+/','aaaaaa',$txt));
```

Using single quotes around the pattern is crucial so that `$config` isn't interpreted as a variable.  As a result, all of the single quotes inside of the pattern must be escaped.

Output:

```
fggfhfghfghf

$config['website'] = 'aaaaaa';


asdasdasdasdasdas
```