# php preg_replace strings with brackets

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace some text if it isn't preceded with a dot (.), but my function seems to result include an unexpected slash ...

```
<?php

$test="function insertXYZ(e){e.insertXYZ()};";
$search="insertXYZ(";
$replace="zzzz(";

$search=str_replace("(", '\(', $search);
//echo $search."\n\n";
$pattern = '\b' . $search;
$replaceException="999";

$test=preg_replace('/' . "\.".$pattern . '/', "$replaceException", $test);
$test=preg_replace('/' . $pattern . '/', $replace, $test);
$test=preg_replace('/' . $replaceException . '/', ".$search", $test);

echo $test;
?>
```

A sample of this code can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24cab4eece20d22a11dd887da44d63e393b51aa9

which outputs...

```
function zzzz(e){e.insertXYZ\()};
                            ^
```

but I want the output to read...

```
function zzzz(e){e.insertXYZ()};
                            ^
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're losing sight of your values as you go. Output/inspect the variable values after each step, and you'll see why the value of $search with the backslash in it is being placed into your final value.

Comment: Use this to automatically escape your search string: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because in this line, you're adding the backslash and then never remove it

```php
$search=str_replace("(", '\(', $search);
```

You could change your code to the following so that you don't need to manually escape this bracket.

```php
// $search=str_replace("(", '\(', $search); <-- Removed
$pattern = '\b' . preg_quote($search);
```

However, you could get the same output with much less code

```php
$testString = "function insertXYZ(e){e.insertXYZ()};";
$regex = "/[^.](insertXYZ)/s";
echo(preg_replace($regex, " zzzz", $testString));
```

```
[^.] - Character group looking where there's NOT a dot character
(insertXYZ) - matches 'insertXYZ' exactly (case sensitive)
/s - Single line modifier so there's no need to escape the dot character
```

Comment: Thanks Lucan; I notice on your "much less code" version, you put in a space before the zzzz; is there any way to avoid this (as the $testString might not have a preceding space). Also - what if the line started with "insertXYZ" (as opposed to "function insertXYZ")?

Comment: I added the space to keep the code short as an example but otherwise, you would need to [modify the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44935992/11916773) so that it could replace only the first group, not the whole match. Regex has a special start of line identifier `^` which you can use to signify the start.